# Protege 3.5 - Unmarshal Exception

Tags: protege

Problem: Cannot run Protege 3.5 in server mode due to:

```
SEVERE: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
...
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.smi.protege.server.Server_Stub
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
```

Tried different JRE/JDK versions before identifying workaround:

In run_protege_server.sh, ensure the rmiregistry also has the codebase set

```
$JAVA_PATH/rmiregistry -J$CODEBASE &
$JAVA_PATH/java -cp $CLASSPATH $TX $OPTIONS $MAINCLASS $SAVE_INTERVAL $METAPROJECT
```

Maybe helpful for someone...